# Electron energy shells/ levels

Tags: quantum-chemistry, energy, electrons

Essentially, I am told electron shell closest to the nucleus is the lowest energy level and subsequent shells have higher energy (I.e. those further from the nucleus).
But..... electrons in the furthest shell require the least amount of energy to remove them, so why is this not the lowest energy level?
I think I may be conflating different concepts,  but want to understand the fundamentals so that I can build on that.
Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Think of the energy levels like steps going down into a hole in the ground. If an object is on a step way down in the hole, it takes more energy to lift it out than if the object was on a step much higher up, near the rim of the hole.

Answer (score 0):

As an electron moves from a higher, further from the nucleus, energy level to a level closer to the nucleus it releases energy as a photon. The electron is now of lower energy. The electron is in effect the orbital it occupies so the orbital is of low energy by association. The lowest energy orbital is the 1s orbital [except in the case of K-capture]. Spontaneity involves loss of energy and increase of entropy so the only way to remove an electron is by a surfeit of energy: high temperature [flame], an appropriate photon flux [uv or xray], or high impulse mechanical action [steel on flint, thunderheads, high energy electrons in a scanning electron microscope]. Read about atomic emission and atomic absorption spectrometry to get a better feel for both the absorption and emission of energy.